# How to match a circuit relay online

Tags: power-electronics

I don't know where to turn to get an answer to this and I hope this is not the wrong setting to ask for this.
I am looking for this Song Chuan relay ([image: Washing machine motor driver relay] and I prefer not to order it clear from China.  How do I go about to match this unless no other manufacturer makes it.  If I need any relay how do I type it online instead of having to deal with all kinds of things I have to shuffle through and still nothing.  I think this is a pretty complicated business.
If the manufacturer's name is worn out on a relay, one could be in for an interesting obstacle course to match it online.  It appears that only by knowing the manufacturer's name one can zero in for a particular relay.
What am I missing?
How would you match this relay and buy it here in the U.S. somewhere?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

For this specific relay, a quick search returns many results. One of them is from [Mouser](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Song-Chuan/812H-1C-C-12VDC?qs=b4gJvg5HYEuAPW6gIXgj4g%3D%3D), an electronics component source.

There is a link on the web site for the data sheet for the relay. Some of the information presented on the linked page indicates that this is a single pole double throw relay (SPDT) with a coil voltage of 12 vdc and a maximum contact current capability of 12 amperes.

You can find similar relays that match those figures and the others in the table of specifications. If you find, for example, a relay that matches all other values, but has a higher current capacity, there's no disadvantage (other than possible higher cost) to using that relay.

If pin placement is critical, you'll find that in the data sheet and would have to ensure that your matched relay also fits those specifications.

Comment: That particular one from Mouser seems to be very low amperage and of course on order.  The one I need is 20A at 120VAC and 15A at 240VAC.  A few days ago I  could only find it on eBay and ordered it, coming clear from China and of course, it has not even left their warehouse yet.